# how to get 5x5 grid in repeater control

Tags: asp.net, repeater

I want to use a repeater as a 5x5 grid.  I have 25 records and I want to display them in 5 rows and 5 columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @brian chandley that the DataList control is an easy to use control. If you're prefer to use a casual table though, you could try the following - in the xml side:

```
<asp:Table ID="myTable" runat="server">

</asp:Table>
```

In some event in the code behind (presumably load or some click event)

```
    List<string> myEmployerList = yourFunctionToPopulateList();

    TableRow row = null;
    for(int j=0;j<myEmployerList.Count;j++)
    {
        if (j % 5 == 0) row = new TableRow();
        TableCell cell = new TableCell();
        cell.Text = myEmployerList[j];
        row.Cells.Add(cell);
        if (j % 5 == 4) myTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    if(j % 5 != 4) myTable.Rows.Add(row); // Catch uneven rows at the end
```

Comment: thnx every .. you guyz are right i should use datalist ... thnx for giving me both solution

Answer (score 0):

Is the repeater a requirement? If not use the DataList instead. It does exactly what you want: It allows you to crate Columns. It manages when to create new Columns vs Rows.

See this description. 
http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/aspnet/doc/ctrlref/data/datalist.aspx

Comment: thnx .. you guyz are right i should use datalist ... thnx for giving me both solution

Answer (score 0):

.aspx:

```
    <table class="gridTable" >
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column1 Display Header</th>
                <th>Column2 Display Header</th>
                <th>Column1 Display Header</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <asp:Repeater ID="grd_data" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Eval("SqlTableColumn1")%></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("SqlTableColumn2")%></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("SqlTableColumn3")%></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

.cs:

```
grd_data.DataSource = _dataTable; //(DataTable)_dataTable => is sent by SQL
grd_data.DataBind();
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you mean an html table when you say "grid", simply place the  tags outside the Repeater and the table rows inside:

```
<table>
    <asp:Repeater ID="foo" DataSource="bla" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td>Col 1</td>
                <td>Col 2</td>
                ...
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</table>
```